ROS internally calculated bandwidth for a topic is 10x smaller than when measured with iftop
We're transmitting camera feeds from a NVidia AGX Orin to a laptop and viewing with Foxglove. The camera feeds are analog NTSC captured with a frame grabber at 30Hz. We're using ROS Melodic and Ubuntu 20.04.6. The below table encapsulates the problem. We've tried three topics to transmit - Image/CompressedImage/CompressedVideo. Compressed video is a special encoding provided by foxglove. For some reason, the bandwidth to transmit this data is enormous, and doesn't pass the smell test for being a realistic outcome.
Recorded bandwidth date
I'm hoping has seen this before and can point me in the right direction to resolve the issue.
Thank you!

Don't use ROS pub/sub for video streaming, use webrtc: https://transitiverobotics.com/blog/streaming-video-from-robots
